# Need to move only those subfolders from folder A to folder B that are 30 days old and do not exist in B

Tags: vbscript

I Need to move only those subfolders from folder A to folder B that are 30 days old. If folder B already contains a folder with the same name as the one being moved, then rename the folder being moved with _1 or simply don't move the folder. The code I have so far is:

```
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
set objFol = fso.GetFolder("T:\Collections\PPA\Cecelia Nero") 
set objSubFolders = objFol.SubFolders 
set fso2 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
set Dest = fso2.GetFolder("T:\Collections\PPA General\")

For each folder in objSubFolders 
  If not fso.FolderExists(Dest) Then
  If DateDiff("d", folder.DateLastModified, Now) > 30 Then
  fso.Movefolder folder, "T:\Collections\PPA General\" 
end if
end if
Next
```

Comment: So, what problem are you experiencing? What's wrong? And one note: you don't need 2 FSO objects. Just one will do--you can use it over and over.

Answer (score 0):

```
If not fso.FolderExists(Dest) Then
```

This check doesn't do what you seem to expect. You want to verify that the folder you want to copy doesn't exist in the destination folder, but the above line only checks if the destination folder itself doesn't exist. Change it into this:

```
If Not fso.FolderExists(fso.BuildPath(Dest.Path, folder.Name)) Then
```

For appending numbers to the copied folder when a destination folder with the same name already exists you could do something like this:

```
For Each sf In objFol.SubFolders
  If DateDiff("d", folder.DateLastModified, Now) > 30 Then
    destFolder = fso.BuildPath(Dest.Path, sf.Name)
    i = 0
    Do While fso.FolderExists(destFolder)
      i = i + 1
      destFolder = fso.BuildPath(Dest.Path, sf.Name & "_" & i)
    Loop
    sf.Move destFolder
Next
```